# What is the "In-House Distribution" profile on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, configuration-profiles

I was just looking around my iPhone and noticed that I have a profile named "In-House Distribution" installed (under `Settings` > `General` > `Profile`). It has a received date of November 18, 2013. The thing is, I have no idea where it came from. My employer didn't install it, I don't recall accepting any profiles, and I simply have no idea where it came from.

**My question:** Should I be worried about this?

Theories:

- I understand that Apple uses "in-house distribution" provisioning for iOS developers. I don't develop iOS apps, but I am currently running the alpha version of the Stack Exchange iOS app (released in February 2014). Could this be the reason?
- I do have a couple of favorites from Safari saved to my home screen for easy access; I may have saved the first of these around November. Could saving those links have caused creation of this profile?

Comment: Same exact issue here (including having installed the Stack Exchange app). Also deleted with no ill effects observed yet.

Comment: The in house app allowes things to be downloaded automatically (news papers magazine ect) it' also alowes certain app to auto update as well

Comment: This is not really relevant to my question. I'm not asking about an app, but about a profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't know what it does, and its of no importance, simply remove it...
also do a iCloud backup before

Comment: Well, that's the question: I don't know what it does, so I don't know *if* it's of any importance.

Comment: well, logic dictates. if it is something important, you would know... also a proper backup before will do the trick IF you feel you'd made a mistake

you know the simplest answer is most often correct

Comment: I probably will end up nuking it, but I still would like to know what it is, preferably before I nuke it.

Comment: hahahah, funny i understand, tho the alpha app is probably the reason.. but i guess you'll find out soon enough! Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: I've deleted it. No ill effects so far, but we'll see. I have a suspicion it may have to do with special licensing my former employer had for in-app content for one particular app; maybe the phone somehow got re-provisioned even after I changed jobs.

Comment: that would make sense